# Parsing of String having multiple nested delimiters of same type

Tags: java, string, string-parsing

I have a problem with parsing of this string:

A-B&1-2-3&4-5-6&C-D

Above string can have multiple nested delimiters and inner string contains delimiter same as of outer-delimiter.

How can I split above string to have something like this:

A

B

1-2-3

4-5-6

C

D

Is there any parsing algorithm that I can implement to parse this string or any Java classes to achieve the same.
This is just an example and the delimiter nesting can be at any level.So, I need some generic logic to handle parsing of string having n level of nesting.

Comment: Where is 1-2-3 coming from? There is no 1?

Comment: Thanks Diego for pointing the typo

Comment: Why is `A-B` split into `A`,`B`, but `1-2-3` is not?

Comment: Its the requirement. Real string will be some big string contains many objects and on the basis of delimiters I need to identify the objects

Comment: As it stands, I think you will need more information to go on in addition to delimiters.  Should ask yourself if strings `A`, `B`, `C`, & `D` have more identifying information that is different from `1-2-3`?

Comment: You can go through the string. Store answer in a variable till you hit `-` push that in the array and then go on doing the same thing. However to handle `1-2-3` you can place a condition, if there is `&` store the whole thing in one string variable till you hit `&` again.

Comment: @zec - No, This is the problem. A, b etc objects have no additional information apart from delimiter.